# Field value not turning up in request.POST querydict - python django

Tags: python, django

I'm sure I'm doing something really obviously wrong, but I can't see it.

I've made a simple form for a Django app, but it's only returning the csrf token, not the field value. The form submits fine, but there's no 'event-title' key/value pair in the QueryDict.

To be precise, when I log the QueryDict, it looks like this:

```
<QueryDict: {u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'dpXmMHTE3WmQvdvrAUD4oFer2WfKEjWd']}>
```

**create_event.html:**

```
{% extends "basic-layout.html" %}
{% block maincontent %}     
    <h1>Create Event</h1>

    {% if error_message %}<p>{{ error_message }}</p>{% endif %}

    <form action="/create-event" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        <label for="event-title">Event title</label>
        <input type="text" title="event-title" id="event-title" required/>
        <input type="submit" value="create event"/>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', views.listEvents),
    url(r'^create-event',  csrf_exempt(views.createEvent))
]
```

views.py

```
def createEvent(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        template = loader.get_template('create_event.html')
        context = RequestContext(request, {})
        return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        logger = logging.getLogger('degub')
        logger.info(request.POST)
        event_title = request.POST.get('event-title', '')
        if event_title:
            event = Event(event_title)
            c = {}
            c.update(csrf(request))
            template = loader.get_template('list_events.html')
            context = RequestContext(request, c)
            return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
        else:
            template = loader.get_template('create_event.html')
            template_values = {"error_message": "Nope, didn't work"}
            context = RequestContext(request, template_values)
            return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

Comment: Your input does not have a name. `<input type="text" name="event-title"  title="event-title" id="event-title" required/>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the `name` attribute in your input tag.

```
<input type="text" name="event-title" title="event-title" id="event-title" required/>
```

Comment: Aha! Find and replace 'name' for 'title' was not my friend, there. Thanks!